# What sort of Spanish are they speaking in this video?

Tags: definiciones

I like watching videos to learn and I used to watch a show from Spain but the Spanish in this video (http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=VPGo3t5qTZ4) seems different somehow.  What kind is it? And, is this dialect particular to a country?

Comment: http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_trampas_del_deseo

Comment: Definitively mexican (I'm mexican by the way, they have a Mexico City accent)

Answer (score 8):

It is not a dialect. It is Spanish with mexican accent. It seems to be an episode of a Mexican TV show.

Comment: So, it uses the same vocabulary as Spain? Some words sound different than a show in Madrid I watched. They use different words for general stuff like goodbye etc. I think..

Comment: @verve no, it doesn't. For instance, *vale* is mostly used in Spain, as are lots of other terms.

Comment: It's the same as other languanges,  for example english, you can note diferences between usa, jamaica, australia, brithish, etc

Comment: Do Madrid and Mexico pronounce the same words differently though?

Comment: @verve Different countries pronounce different phonemes differently. For example, in most of Central and South America, as far as I know, the "soft" C sound (not the K sound) is pronounced as if it were an "S". 

For example, for the word "cocido" a spaniard would say something like "kozido", whereas a mexican would pronounce "kosido". 
Did I explain that somewhat properly?

Comment: Yes, it's a Mexican TV Show but the audio is saturated and it is hard to understand what they are saying.

Comment: It is a dialect... all spoken languages are spoken in a dialect. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's Mexican Spanish. It's no more a dialect than Irish English or Swedish German.  If you want to know more, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexican_Spanish) has excellent articles on regional variations of spanish. I'm particularly fond of [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chilean_Spanish).